# Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that an inequality holds true

Tags: inequality, contest-math, problem-solving, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I just came across the following problem:

Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that:

$(a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)(b^5+b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1)(a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)\ge 8(a^2+a+1)(b^2+b+1)(c^2+c+1)$

I proved it in the following fashion:

$(a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)(b^5+b^4+b^3+b^2+b+1)(a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)=(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)(a^2+a+1)(b^2+b+1)(c^2+c+1)$

So we just have to prove that $(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)\ge 8$, which is true from the following:

$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1)=(a^3b^3+a^3+b^3+1)(c^3+1)=a^3b^3c^3+1+a^3b^3+a^3c^3+b^3c^3+a^3+b^3+c^3$

$=2+a^3b^3+a^3c^3+b^3c^3+a^3+b^3+c^3$

$\ge2+3\sqrt[3]{a^6b^6c^6}+3\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}$

$=8$

So it holds true, so the inequality is proved.

I am wondering what other solutions exist to this problem, could you please post up alternative approaches?

Comment: By the way, I believe that my proof is correct, however if you find a flaw in it, please tell me about it

Comment: After "I proved it in the following fashion:" you have a typo: $a^2 + a + a$.

Comment: oh thanks @DávidLaczkó editing it now

Comment: Given the way that your first factoring step *directly dovetails* into the problem's *syntax*, I suspect that your solution is the intended one.  There could still be other (somewhat unrelated) solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your idea, we need to prove
$$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1) \geqslant 8.$$
**Proof 1.** Using the AM-GM inequality we have
$$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1) \geqslant 2\sqrt{a^3} \cdot 2\sqrt{b^3} \cdot 2\sqrt{c^3} = 8\sqrt{a^3b^3c^3} = 8.$$
**Proof 2.** According to the Holder inequality, we have
$$(a^3+1)(b^3+1)(c^3+1) \geqslant \big(\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}+1\big)^3 = (abc+1)^3 =   8.$$